# How can I add differents elements in the same array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays

I am a very new in Python so please forgive me the basic question.

I have an array with 400 float elements, and I need to add the first term with the second and divide by two.

I was trying something like:

```
x1=[0,...,399]

n = len(x1)

x2 = []

i = 0
for i in range(0,n): 
    x2[i]=(x1[i]+x1[i+1])/2
```

But it gives me the error: `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try `x2.append((x1[i] + x1[i + 1]) / 2)`

Comment: Try doing `for i in range(n-1):`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you cannot assign a value to an index in a list that is higher than the length of the list.  Since you just want to keep adding items to the list, use the `list.append()` method instead:

```
n = len(x1)

x2 = []

i = 0
for i in range(n-1): 
    x2.append((x1[i]+x1[i+1])/2)
```

Note that I also decreased the range by one, otherwise `x1[i+1]` will cause an IndexError.

Answer (score 1):

A shorter and faster one-line  solution using list comprehensions:

```
x1=range(0,400)  #use xrange if on python 2.7
x2=[(x1[i]+x1[i+1])/2 for i in range(len(x1)) if i<len(x1)-1]
```

Comment: Why use enumerate if you're not using `x`?  ISTM the shorter listcomp way would be `[(x+y)/2.0 for x,y in zip(x1, x1[1:])]`.

Comment: replaced `enumerate` with `range`, didn't used zip because this is what came to my mind when I was solving this.

Answer (score 1):

The most succinct way I can think of expressing this:

```
[(i + j)/2 for i, j in zip(xrange(400), xrange(1,400))]
```

Or, equivalently:

```
xs = range(400)
[(i + j)/2 for i, j in zip(xs, xs[1:])]
```

Obviously, in Python3, `xrange` is obsolete, so there you could use `range` instead. Also, in Python3, the default behavior of `/` changes, so you'd have to use `//` instead if you want integers.

Answer (score 0):

FP-pythonic way:

```
x1 = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
x2 = map(lambda x, y: (x + y) / 2, x1, [0] + x1[:-1])
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `map` here?